# WPF- What does exit code -1 represents

Tags: c#, wpf, winapi, windows-10, interop

I have been building a sample WPF Application. I have used some undocumented codes like `SetWindowCompositionAttribute()` method. Once I run my application it works fine without any problem but when i exit my application using alt+F4 I got a message in the output window.

> The program '[10172] Sample.exe' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).

I think there is some kind of error occurred. I know that the exit code `0` represents the program executed without any errors.

Does this `-1` represents any kind of memory leak? How can i debug and check what error is it causing.

For reference, Here is my code which causes the issue:

```
public static void SetHBrush(IntPtr hwnd, uint brush) {
    var accent = new AccentPolicy {
        AccentState = AccentState.ACCENT_ENABLE_GRADIENT,
        GradientColor = brush // 0xFFFFFF
    };
    var accentStructSize = Marshal.SizeOf(accent);
    var accentPtr = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(accentStructSize);
    Marshal.StructureToPtr(accent, accentPtr, false);
    var data = new WindowCompositionAttributeData {
        Attribute = WindowCompositionAttribute.WCA_ACCENT_POLICY,
        SizeOfData = accentStructSize,
        Data = accentPtr
    };
    NativeMethods.SetWindowCompositionAttribute(hwnd, ref data);
    Marshal.FreeHGlobal(accentPtr);
}
```

Here is the link where i have fetched the code : [sample-win32-acrylicblur](https://github.com/riverar/sample-win32-acrylicblur/blob/master/MainWindow.xaml.cs)

Comment: Is there anything in the event log?

Comment: No Nothing. i think it's because of the undocumented api issue.it occurs some times only not always.

Comment: Hi @trickymind, I wrote the code sample you linked to. I was able to indeed reproduce the error once, then when I attached the debugger, it went away. So the hunt begins. Stay tuned.

Comment: @RafaelRivera, Thank you, i have been using your code for a long time. since SetWindowCompositionAttribute() is changing in every version of windows.it is very difficult to fix errors based in each builds. Last time ACCENT_INVALID_STATE gives transparent window like WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP now its value is changed to AccentState enum value 6. But when i use the spy++ to inspect window styles it doesn't show WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP style but the window gives a very similar behaviour(Transparent).

Comment: @trickymind Yep, the downsides of using undocumented APIs I'm afraid. I can't reproduce the -1 anymore but I'm going to guess a thread internal to WPF is exiting with -1 and that's bubbling up. (You could override the exit code via Environment.ExitCode but you'll potentially hide bugs this way.)

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier not to call undocumented apis

Comment:  Hiding Bugs!!, but when the code is open source its going to be a bad approach. i am  using your code not to create the acrylic effect but for getting transparency in WPF without loosing the window Borders and shadows(WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP in win32), i was not able to set WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP through SetWindowLong() in wpf (it wont work). For the acrylic blur i was using : https://github.com/microsoft/Windows.UI.Composition-Win32-Samples/tree/master/dotnet/WPF/AcrylicEffect  , it was laggy until 1903 but seems to be fixed in 19042.

Comment: will there be any other way to use WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP in WPF